# Updating in game with normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, game-theory

In a game from the following [paper](https://www.princeton.edu/~smorris/pdfs/paper_36_Global_Games.pdf), it is stated that

> Player $i$ observes a private signal $x_i = \theta + \epsilon_i$. Each $\epsilon_i$ is independently normally distributed with mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. We assume that $\theta$ is randomly drawn from the real line, with each realization equally likely. This implies that a player observing signal $x$ considers $\theta$ to be distributed normally with mean $x$ and standard deviation
>   $\sigma$. This in turn implies that he thinks his opponent’s signal $x$ is normally
>   distributed with mean $x$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{2}\sigma$. The assumption that $\theta$ is uniformly distributed on the real line is nonstandard, but presents no technical difficulties

Can someone please help me understand why $x_1\mid x_2\sim N(x_2,2\sigma^2)$?

Comment: You made quite a few mistakes when copying this question (which doesn't resolve where the $\sqrt{2}$ comes from).

Comment: I hope I corrected all of them. Thanks @mathse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ f_{X_1,X_2,\theta}(x_1,x_2,t)=f_{\varepsilon_1}(x_1-t)\cdot f_{\varepsilon_2}(x_2-t)\cdot f_\theta(t)$$

"integrate" over $t$ using $f_\theta(t)=1$ to get $$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$$ proportional to $$ \exp\left(-(x_1-x_2)^2/(4\sigma^2)\right)$$

do a similar reasoning to get $f_{X_2}$ and then use Bayes' rule.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible you can add a few more comments. I am still not sure exactly what is going on. For example, I am not sure how you make the first expansion in equation 1. And what is $t$?

Comment: $t$ is just a realization of $\theta$ the random variable. I guess you should just read more about basic probability. I'm not trying to dismiss your question but if the joint distribution of $X_1$, $X_2$ and $\theta$ is not self-explanatory then I stronly recommend you to review: Bayes' rule, convolutions and iterated expectations. Any decent probability book should cove this topics. Respectfully, S.

Comment: @SegioParreiras Thank you. I think I get it now. I just "forgot" that the $epsilons$ were independent. And your right. I proberly should read up on some basic probability theory :)

Comment: @RudFaden: You are welcome and welcome to Stack Exchange. If my answer was somewhat useful, the usual way to say "thank you" is by up voting it and/or accepting it as an answer by clicking the check mark. Accepting a questions earns points for the answer but also for you as well.